# I have the birth years, I want to find the Average Age

Tags: sql, ms-access, average, subtraction

I want to find the average ages of the people. The field fldBorn is a `number` field. Therefore it cannot be done by `datediff`.

[[image: Table]]

```
SELECT AVG(SELECT 2016-fldBorn FROM tblPerson)
FROM tblPerson
```

Comment: Can you write examples of rows for field fldBorn?

Comment: Not sure why you need the inner select... `SELECT AVG(2016-fldborn) From tblPerson`

Comment: Do what @xQbert suggests. You are making it too complicated.

Comment: 2016 minus the year born is not the age, however. The real age must be caluculated from the *date* of birth and the current *day* of course.

Answer (score 0):

I am such an idiot, This is the answer. It was so simple, yet wasted so much of my time. Anyway if it helps someone else I will be happy

```
SELECT Avg(2016-fldBorn) AS Expr1
FROM tblPerson;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't hard code the current year in your SQL statement. 2016 works now, but in 2017, it will be wrong.

```
SELECT AVG(YEAR(Date())-fldBorn) FROM tblPerson
```